# jspm install to a different folder

Tags: jspm

I want jspm to install to a different directory (wwwroot), so it needs to put it's config.js and jspm_packages folder there.  But I want config.js to not include wwwroot because when you're on the website, that is the root () and when it looks for wwwroot\jspm_packages, it is unable to find them.  Is there any way to do this?

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-aspnetcore-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Angular2 with Asp.net Core starter kit.",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Ryan Langton",
  "license": "ISC",
  "jspm": {
    "directories": {
      "packages": "wwwroot/jspm_packages" // <- need wwwroot for jspm install
    },
    "configFile": "wwwroot/config.js",    // <- need wwwroot for jspm install
    "dependencies": {
      "angular2": "npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.1",
      "angular2-polyfill": "npm:angular2-polyfill@^0.0.1",
      "es6-shim": "github:es-shims/es6-shim@^0.34.1",
      "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2",
      "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.0",
      "zonejs": "npm:zone.js@^0.5.10"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.1",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.13",
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "~2.10.0",
    "gulp-watch": "~4.3.5",
    "jspm": "^0.16.24",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.5.10"
  }
}
```

## config.js

This file is created by the "json install" command which is part of the build process.

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "babel",
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system"
    ]
  },
  paths: {
    "github:*": "wwwroot/jspm_packages/github/*",  // <-- this is wrong, do not want wwwroot here!
    "npm:*": "wwwroot/jspm_packages/npm/*"     // <-- this is wrong, do not want wwwroot here!
  },

  map: {
    "angular2": "npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.1",
    "angular2-polyfill": "npm:angular2-polyfill@0.0.1",
    "babel": "npm:babel-core@5.8.34",
    "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.34",
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.6",
    "es6-shim": "github:es-shims/es6-shim@0.34.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zonejs": "npm:zone.js@0.5.10",
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0": {
      "assert": "npm:assert@1.3.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0": {
      "buffer": "npm:buffer@3.6.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-constants@0.1.0": {
      "constants-browserify": "npm:constants-browserify@0.0.1"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0": {
      "crypto-browserify": "npm:crypto-browserify@3.11.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1": {
      "events": "npm:events@1.0.2"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0": {
      "path-browserify": "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2": {
      "process": "npm:process@0.11.2"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0": {
      "stream-browserify": "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-string_decoder@0.1.0": {
      "string_decoder": "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0": {
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-vm@0.1.0": {
      "vm-browserify": "npm:vm-browserify@0.0.4"
    },
    "npm:angular2-polyfill@0.0.1": {
      "angular": "npm:angular@1.4.9",
      "camelcase": "npm:camelcase@2.0.1",
      "dot-prop": "npm:dot-prop@2.2.0"
    },
    "npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.1": {
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "es6-promise": "npm:es6-promise@3.0.2",
      "es6-shim": "npm:es6-shim@0.33.13",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2",
      "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.0",
      "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@0.5.10"
    },
    "npm:angular@1.4.9": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:asn1.js@4.3.0": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.6.4",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "minimalistic-assert": "npm:minimalistic-assert@1.0.0",
      "vm": "github:jspm/nodelibs-vm@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:assert@1.3.0": {
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.34": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:browserify-aes@1.0.5": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "buffer-xor": "npm:buffer-xor@1.0.3",
      "cipher-base": "npm:cipher-base@1.0.2",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "evp_bytestokey": "npm:evp_bytestokey@1.0.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:browserify-cipher@1.0.0": {
      "browserify-aes": "npm:browserify-aes@1.0.5",
      "browserify-des": "npm:browserify-des@1.0.0",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "evp_bytestokey": "npm:evp_bytestokey@1.0.0"
    },
    "npm:browserify-des@1.0.0": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "cipher-base": "npm:cipher-base@1.0.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "des.js": "npm:des.js@1.0.0",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1"
    },
    "npm:browserify-rsa@4.0.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.6.4",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "constants": "github:jspm/nodelibs-constants@0.1.0",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "randombytes": "npm:randombytes@2.0.2"
    },
    "npm:browserify-sign@4.0.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.6.4",
      "browserify-rsa": "npm:browserify-rsa@4.0.0",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "create-hmac": "npm:create-hmac@1.1.4",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "elliptic": "npm:elliptic@6.1.0",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "parse-asn1": "npm:parse-asn1@5.0.0",
      "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:buffer-xor@1.0.3": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:buffer@3.6.0": {
      "base64-js": "npm:base64-js@0.0.8",
      "child_process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-child_process@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "ieee754": "npm:ieee754@1.1.6",
      "isarray": "npm:isarray@1.0.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:cipher-base@1.0.2": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0",
      "string_decoder": "github:jspm/nodelibs-string_decoder@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:constants-browserify@0.0.1": {
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:core-js@1.2.6": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:core-util-is@1.0.2": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:create-ecdh@4.0.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.6.4",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "elliptic": "npm:elliptic@6.1.0"
    },
    "npm:create-hash@1.1.2": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "cipher-base": "npm:cipher-base@1.0.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "ripemd160": "npm:ripemd160@1.0.1",
      "sha.js": "npm:sha.js@2.4.4"
    },
    "npm:create-hmac@1.1.4": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:crypto-browserify@3.11.0": {
      "browserify-cipher": "npm:browserify-cipher@1.0.0",
      "browserify-sign": "npm:browserify-sign@4.0.0",
      "create-ecdh": "npm:create-ecdh@4.0.0",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "create-hmac": "npm:create-hmac@1.1.4",
      "diffie-hellman": "npm:diffie-hellman@5.0.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "pbkdf2": "npm:pbkdf2@3.0.4",
      "public-encrypt": "npm:public-encrypt@4.0.0",
      "randombytes": "npm:randombytes@2.0.2"
    },
    "npm:des.js@1.0.0": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "minimalistic-assert": "npm:minimalistic-assert@1.0.0"
    },
    "npm:diffie-hellman@5.0.1": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.6.4",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "miller-rabin": "npm:miller-rabin@4.0.0",
      "randombytes": "npm:randombytes@2.0.2",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:elliptic@6.1.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.6.4",
      "brorand": "npm:brorand@1.0.5",
      "hash.js": "npm:hash.js@1.0.3",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:es6-promise@3.0.2": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:es6-shim@0.33.13": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:evp_bytestokey@1.0.0": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:hash.js@1.0.3": {
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1"
    },
    "npm:inherits@2.0.1": {
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:miller-rabin@4.0.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.6.4",
      "brorand": "npm:brorand@1.0.5"
    },
    "npm:parse-asn1@5.0.0": {
      "asn1.js": "npm:asn1.js@4.3.0",
      "browserify-aes": "npm:browserify-aes@1.0.5",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "evp_bytestokey": "npm:evp_bytestokey@1.0.0",
      "pbkdf2": "npm:pbkdf2@3.0.4",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:pbkdf2@3.0.4": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "child_process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-child_process@0.1.0",
      "create-hmac": "npm:create-hmac@1.1.4",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:process@0.11.2": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:public-encrypt@4.0.0": {
      "bn.js": "npm:bn.js@4.6.4",
      "browserify-rsa": "npm:browserify-rsa@4.0.0",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "create-hash": "npm:create-hash@1.1.2",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "parse-asn1": "npm:parse-asn1@5.0.0",
      "randombytes": "npm:randombytes@2.0.2"
    },
    "npm:randombytes@2.0.2": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:readable-stream@1.1.13": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "core-util-is": "npm:core-util-is@1.0.2",
      "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "isarray": "npm:isarray@0.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "stream-browserify": "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0",
      "string_decoder": "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31"
    },
    "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.3": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:ripemd160@1.0.1": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.0": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:sha.js@2.4.4": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0": {
      "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "readable-stream": "npm:readable-stream@1.1.13"
    },
    "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:util@0.10.3": {
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:vm-browserify@0.0.4": {
      "indexof": "npm:indexof@0.0.1"
    },
    "npm:zone.js@0.5.10": {
      "es6-promise": "npm:es6-promise@3.0.2",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I might change my workflow to have config.js and jspm_packages install to the root and then as part of my build process transfer them to wwwroot

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options. Are all your components/custom JS also in wwwroot? If so, I'd just install jspm to that directory and then jspm will just look in the current dir...which will be wwwroot locally, but in production it will just look at your root dir for the website.

A second option, which is also recommended as it is faster, would be to bundle all your dependencies using jspm bundle, and then JSPM will be able to find them correctly. That is just bundle all deps into bundle.js, put that in wwwroot, and then in your index file after you load system.js just do:

```
System.import('./bundle.js').then( () => { ... }
```